# Bounding Summation - Geometric Series

Tags: induction

When proving the bound on a summation in the Analysis of Algorithms when proving the bound also applies to $n+1$ the following inequalities are derived by the induction hypothesis:

$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}3^k + 3^{n+1} \leq c3^n + 3^{n+1}
= \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{c}\right)c3^{n+1} \leq c3^{n+1}$$

I don't quite understand how the second inequality is derived from the first inequality. Would someone be able to explain the math?

Comment: Suppose $c \ge2$. Then $\displaystyle{\frac13}\le\frac12$ and $\displaystyle{\frac1c\le\frac12}$. So,  $\displaystyle{\frac13 + \frac1c\le\frac12+\frac12=1\le 1}$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for [math.se].